# Bitcoin too large file

Tags: synchronization

I installed the bitcoin program and now it's synchronising, and although I installed it on my very large D: disk it's moving all of the stuff on my little C: disk.
It's now around 6 GB in size with 45 weeks to go and I'm out of room. Is there a way I can safely move it to my D: or make it synchronise onto my D: instead?

Comment: Maybe it is a time for you to use thin client, like multibit? Is there any particular reason you are going after full node?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify where to store the blockchain by starting QT with the following command argument:

```
-datadir D:\BITCOIN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either start the bitcoin client with the command line option `-datadir=<path to another directory>` (you would have to do this every time you start the client) or you can link the `blocks` directory to another location. How to do this depends on your operating system:

- For Windows I found this [forum post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=63844.msg748224#msg748224) (didn't test it but sounds reasonable)
- On Linux you could do something like this: `ln -s ~/.bitcoin/blocks /another/directory` (make sure you use an absolute path for the source directory).